# Como insertar el archivo de Spring en un proyecto ya existente

Tags: java, spring, intellij-idea

tengo un proyecto de java en intellij con el cual vengo trabajando, ahora el docente nos dice "*descarguen el archivo de spring inicilizr y hagan lo que sigue*" descargue el archivo con las respectivas dependencias que voy a necesitar pero no se como ni donde insertar los datos del archivo de Spring lo que me tiene trabada y no me deja avanzar; en todos los tutoriales que veo trabajan **PARTIENDO** del proyecto Spring pero no como insertarlo en un proyecto ya avanzado

Ayuda por favor

Comment: aparte de entrar al sitio https://start.spring.io/ y descargar el archivo que mas has hecho?

Comment: Generalmente spring inicilizr se usa para crear tus proyectos, con el lenguaje de programación de tu preferencia, la version de java y las dependencias que vas a usar, cuanto tienes todo configurado le das a Generate el cual te descarga un archivo para que puedas abrir el proyecto con tu IDE favorito. Lo que tienes que agregar es el archivo `pom.xml`, se mas explicita en tu pregunta.

Answer (score 1):

Si quieres seguir con tu proyecto y agregar las nuevas posibles dependencias, debes realizar el delicado proceso de actualizar las dependencias de tu proyecto.

Si tu proyecto original es Maven entonces deberás actualizar el archivo pom.xml, agregando las nuevas dependencias, chequeando las versiones, etc. Es un proceso delicado, si trabajas con Eclipse podrás utilizar algún quickfix si es que existe.

También esta la opción de agregar starters en algunos IDEs.

[image: Eclipse starters]

Si tu proyecto es Gradle deberás actualizar los archivos de Gradle (cosa que yo nunca he intentado hacer)

A veces es mejor partir con el proyecto Spring initializr qué te entregaron e ir agregando el código de tu proyecto antiguo lentamente pero te ahorras los problemas de actualizar tus dependencias y configuraciones.

Para más detalles de como hacerlo deberías compartir los archivos de dependencias de ambos proyectos.

Comment: estoy con el intellij, pero no encontré como sincronizarlo tal como en tu imagen... en ese caso copiare la info del pom únicamente verdad????

Comment: Generalmente es solo agregar las dependencias que te faltan, o sea tu pom le vas agregando las cosas que no tiene. Pero a veces resulta y otras veces no dependiendo de muchos factores, no existe una regla sencilla de como actualizar un pom.